# MySQL is duplicating results

Tags: php, mysql

Running a Select and it is duplicating the results 3 time for the 2nd WHERE clause, can someone help me out. I cannot find anything online to see if I can figure it out myself.

```
        $searchCat = $mysqli->query("
        SELECT 
            business.name, business.street
        FROM 
            business, category
        WHERE 
            (category.category_id = business.category_id AND category.name = '$searchTerm') OR
            (business.search_term_8 = '$searchTerm')
    ")
```

It goes away when I use GROUP BY, if that is how it works great but I am concerned that it is not suppose to do that.

I definetly do not have any duplicate records in the table at this time.

Out put looks like this:

- City Grill, 2841 E Sprague st - 5
- Chappy's Restaurant, 13 Main St - 5
- Chappy's Restaurant, 13 Main St - 5
- Chappy's Restaurant, 13 Main St - 5
- Howie's Pizza Bar, 552 Ace St - 5
- Howie's Pizza Bar, 552 Ace St - 5
- Howie's Pizza Bar, 552 Ace St - 5
- House Inc, 123 - 5

Tables:

*category*

- category_id :: **1, 2, 3**
- name :: **bar, restaurant, spa**

*business*

- business_id :: **1, 2, 3, 4**
- business.name :: **City Grill, Chappy's, Howie's; House Inc**
- business.street :: **street info**
- category_id :: **1, ,1,1**
- search_term_1 :: **empty**
- ---thru **all are empty**
- search_term_8 :: **bar**

Searching for "bar"

Answer (score 2):

Seems wrong where clause, try this:

```
$searchCat = $mysqli->query("
        SELECT 
            business.name, business.street
        FROM 
            business, category
        WHERE 
            category.category_id = business.category_id AND 
        (category.name = '$searchTerm' OR business.search_term_8 = '$searchTerm')
    ")
```

Comment: Ok, that gives me two duplicates for one result - trying to post results

Comment: - City Grill, 2841 E Sprague st - 5
 - Chappy's Restaurant, 13 Main St - 5
 - Chappy's Restaurant, 13 Main St - 5
 - Howie's Pizza Bar, 552 Ace St - 5
 - House Inc, 123 - 5

Comment: can you share the data you have in two tables and the term you are searching for?

Comment: I added to my original question

Comment: @harkly: the cause for duplication (actually triplication) is an implicit cartesian product between category and business, because on the second filter (after the OR) you didn't link the two tables. it's triplicated because category has three lines.

Comment: It ended up not working, after playing around with the table I noticed it did not run the last part  "OR business.search_term_8 = '$searchTerm'"

Comment: @Daniela, yes I noticed that when playing around with the table's data.

Answer (score 1):

Without a reproducible test case it's hard to tell what's going on here, but at first it seems to me that you are not filtering the data correctly.

The 'OR' term in your WHERE clause definitely seems to be the culprit, since it can add duplicate rows to your result set depending on the dataset. It helps to think that the OR is actually an UNION ALL of two queries... in your cause, your query would be equivalent to:

```
SELECT business.name, 
       business.street
  FROM business, category
 WHERE category.category_id = business.category_id 
   AND category.name = '$searchTerm'
 UNION ALL
SELECT business.name, 
       business.street
  FROM business, category
 WHERE business.search_term_8 = '$searchTerm'
```

Please note that the filter on the second query only takes into account the "business.search_term_8" filter, which is probably what you do not want to do (and it's giving duplicate results).

Note that you are making an implicit cartesian product between category and business since no condition is linking those two tables on the WHERE clause.

Comment: I have both SELECTs running on their own, the second one doesn't dulpicate.  $searchBus = $mysqli->query("SELECT business.name, business.street FROM business WHERE search_term_8 = '$searchTerm'");

Comment: Please share a create table with a sample of your data and what terms are you using on the filter.

Comment: I added to my original question

Answer (score 0):

I added a join and that seems to have solved my issue.

```
        SELECT 
        business.name, business.street
    FROM 
        business
        LEFT JOIN
        category ON category.category_id = business.category_id
    WHERE 
        category.category_id = business.category_id AND category.name = '$searchTerm'
        OR business.search_term_1 = '$searchTerm'
        OR business.search_term_2 = '$searchTerm'
        OR business.search_term_3 = '$searchTerm'
        OR business.search_term_4 = '$searchTerm'
        OR business.search_term_5 = '$searchTerm'
        OR business.search_term_6 = '$searchTerm'
        OR business.search_term_7 = '$searchTerm'
        OR business.search_term_8 = '$searchTerm'
```

Results:

- City Grill, 2841 E Sprague st - 5
- Chappy's Restaurant, 13 Main St - 5
- Howie's Pizza Bar, 552 Ace St - 5
- House Inc, 123 - 5